# Jquery - Work out if any children have a data value greater than 50

Tags: jquery

I have a list with each li having a data-role number.  I need to do something if any one of the child li's have a data-role number above 50

so far have this but it's not working

```
$('ul.chart').each(function(i) {
    var dataRole = $(this).data('role');

    if ($(this).children(dataRole < 51)) {
                alert('all of the children are below 50') 

    }else {
         alert('one or more of the children are above 50')              
    }                  
});
```

Comment: I think what you need is to define a `filter()`. Take a look at the doc: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('ul.chart li').each(function(){
   if ($(this).data('role')>50) {
      alert('one or more of the children are above 50');
      return false; // stops the iteration
   }
});
```

Using filter (but it's equivalent and probably not faster as a new collection is made) :

```
if ($('ul.chart li').filter(function(){ return $(this).data('role')>50 }).length) {
     alert('one or more of the children are above 50');
}
```

For Benjamin, using `every`, you could do this

```
if (!$('li').get().every(function(e){ return $(e).data('role')<50 })) {
     alert('one or more of the children are above 50');
}
```

Comment: Add a solution using `.every` you know you want to :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You lost me. I don't know this function. Should I add it first to $.fn ? Are you referring to filter ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum "Happy now ? :)"

Comment: Yes. Every is the semantic way to do `filter(->).length > 0` that's why it's there :)

Comment: That's true, and sometimes it might be most readable. But the `.each` form would probably be the faster here, as jQuery doesn't provide a direct `every`.

Comment: Every also isn't cross browser. Also you're using an extra map which is nice but could be avoided. Optimally `every` is the fastest functional option here because it stops on the first fail, it's as fast as a native `.forEach` version in theory and faster than _map_. Of course the fastest would have been a for loop. Also, data-attributes are a dumb idea anyway. The logical thing would be to traverse a JS array but you can't win everything can you :)

Comment: I mostly agree but `each` also stops as soon as the test is verified (using `return false`).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
var over50 = $('ul.chart li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('role') > 50;
}).length > 0;
```

That selects all `<li>` elements inside of the `<ul class="chart">` element, then [filters](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) those down only to those that have a `data-role` attribute with a value greater than 50, then checks the length of the resulting object; if it's greater than 0 then there's at least one element.

Then you'd just use `if(over50) { doSomething() }` to perform your conditional logic.

Comment: +1 - Although the OP doesn't ask for such, it could be useful to keep a record of those elements that exceed the threshold with eg. `$over50 = .....});`, leaving out `.length > 0`. Those that don't exceed the threshold would be `$('ul.chart li').not($over50)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('ul.chart li').filter(function(){return $(this).data('role') > 50;}).length > 0){
 // do something, one or more have data-role more then 50
}
```